# How to combine different .csv files to one complete file by adding the data of every file as an additional row using R?

Tags: r, csv, merge, row

I have several different folders which all contain one single .csv file. All of those .csv files have one single column containing the data of one condition of an experiment.
I would like to merge those .csv files in such a way that the data of every file is added as a new column.

At the moment, it Looks somehow like this:

```
C1.csv
102
106
152
196
223
486
553

C2.csv
296
299
843
1033
1996
```

However, it would like to have one single .csv file, where all the separate files are copied into a new column containing the name of the source file, like:

```
C1     C2     ...    Cn
102    296    ...    ...
106    299    ...
152    843    ...
196    1033   ...
223    1996   ...
486           ...
553           ...
```

So far, I the following code:

```
myFiles = list.files(path = ".", recursive = TRUE, pattern = ".csv", full.names = TRUE)
data <- lapply(myFiles, read.table, sep="\t", header=FALSE)
Max <- max(sapply(data, length))
data <- lapply(data, function(x) c(x, rep(NA, Max - length(x))))
data <- do.call(cbind, data)
names(data) <- sub("^[^[:alnum:]]*([[:alnum:]]+)\\.csv$", "\\1", myFiles)

write.csv(data, "outfile.csv")
```

It yielded a document that looks like this instead of adding the data of every .csv file in a new column:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fzjb9.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can read all files using `read.table` in a list. Combine all data using `dplyr::bind_rows`. Afterwards, use `reshape2::dcast` to spread data in wide format with a column for data from every file.

```
# Get list of files in directory
fileList <- list.files(".", "*.csv", full.names = TRUE)

# Read file data. This will generate a list containing dataframes
listData <- lapply(fileList, read.table)

# Name list using name of files
names(listData) <- gsub(".csv","",basename(fileList))

library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)

bind_rows(listData, .id = "FileName") %>%
  group_by(FileName) %>%
  mutate(rowNum = row_number()) %>%
  dcast(rowNum~FileName, value.var = "V1") %>%
  select(-rowNum) %>%
  write.csv(file="Result.csv")

# Content of Result.csv
# "","C1","C2"
# "1",102,296
# "2",106,299
# "3",152,843
# "4",196,1033
# "5",223,1996
# "6",486,NA
# "7",553,NA
```

Comment: This seems to work really well! But how can I save it as a new .csv file? I have entered the code `write_csv(listData, "C:/Users/XYZ/Desktop/Result.csv")` but then this error message appeared: `Error: is.data.frame(x) is not TRUE`. Is it not possible to use `write_csv()`here?

Comment: @Marc You can have a look at answer now. The `result.csv` will contain result. If it works, then you can accept answer by clicking on `tick` symbol in left of answer box.

Comment: Nice one, `basename`, I completely forgot about it.

Comment: Thanks. You got a nice answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?
Note that I read the files in with `scan`. Since the files have **only one column** there is no need for a complex function like `read.csv`.

```
myFiles <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = "^C.*\\.csv", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
data <- lapply(myFiles, scan)
Max <- max(sapply(data, length))
data <- lapply(data, function(x) c(x, rep(NA, Max - length(x))))
data <- do.call(cbind, data)
names(data) <- sub("^[^[:alnum:]]*([[:alnum:]]+)\\.csv$", "\\1", myFiles)

write.csv(data, "outfile.csv")
```

The contents of `"outfile.csv"` are

```
"","V1","V2"
"1",102,296
"2",106,299
"3",152,843
"4",196,1033
"5",223,1996
"6",486,NA
"7",553,NA
```

Comment: It's not yet functioning as it is supposed to be. Now, it yields a .csv document that looks like the one added to the original question.

Comment: This is, what I was looking for. Thank you!