# getting last element from strsplit within sapply

Tags: r, string, apply, sapply

I am parsing some file paths with a `strsplit` within `sapply`, to try to split on / to get elements for a data reorganization. However, not all of the file paths are the same length, and while getting most elements has been easy, using lines of the type

`allFiles_audioOnly$Region<-sapply(strsplit(as.character(allFiles_audioOnly$fullPath), '\\/'),`[`, 3)`

I'm not quite sure what argument to replace the `3` with in order to get the last element of the output. I could try to use some kind of `tail()` or `length()` statement, but I'm not quite sure how to fit that in with the sapply syntax.

Comment: Why not `basename`?

Comment: If you are looking for the just file name then you can use `basename` as suggested by @Parfait. An answer was added recently using `basename` at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50897193/how-to-combine-different-csv-files-to-one-complete-file-by-adding-the-data-of-e/50897760?noredirect=1#comment88799235_50897760

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided any sample data. But you can try as:

```
allFiles_audioOnly$Region <-
 sapply(strsplit(as.character(allFiles_audioOnly$fullPath), '\\/'),
                                               function(x)x[length(x)])
```